Grease Pencil curves do not behave like regular curves during extrusion with Geo Nodes
I am experimenting with Grease Pencil's curve extrusion in Blender 4.3.0 and it seems GP curves are unlike other curves: their origin is at (0,0) and the offset value needed to extrude them is much larger, see below:

Now this is the extrude of a regular bézier curve:

We can see the difference in value in the End handle vector, and origin difference between the two. Is there a way to conform the GP curve to regular curves so they behave the same?
Example project: 

This is obviously a bug. I don't know if you have already reported this or not, but I reported a duplicate of this just in case you didn't. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/130814

I didn't report a bug as I was not sure it was one. Thanks for reporting.

you and I are both wrong here. This actually wasn't a bug. The Profile Curve of the Curve to Mesh node is dictated by the radii of the points in the curve path. Your point radius was set about 100 times smaller than normal. Luckily the solution was simpler than expected. Use a Set Curve Radius node or a Set Point Radius node.

When did you reset the radius of the points from 1.0? When you generated the line in Draw mode with the following line thickness.


Blender 4.3.0

That's a nice workaround, thanks! The origin is still at (0,0) but well, that should not be a big issue.

Ok setting the curve radius solves the problem indeed! On a previous .blend file you posted for some reason setting it had no effect, I thought this was a bug, in the newer file this is working though. Was probably due to the other nodes that were there. Anyway this is indeed not a bug.
